# PHP - Ajax fetch data without refreshing

Tags: php, css, ajax

I am using this exact same tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Created 2 files, one HTML file and one PHP ( Conn/Query ect..) it working great but the only issue is that the table seems to loose its CSS formatting.

Any ideas why? Thanks

**PHP FILE**

```
 echo "<div class='widget'>
<div class='whead'><h6>Search Result</h6><div class='clear'></div></div>
<div id='dyn' class='hiddenpars'>
    <a class='tOptions' title='Options'><img src='assests/images/icons/options' alt='Filter' /></a>
    <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' class='dTable' id='dynamic'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Family</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Location</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";

if ( count($result) ) { 
foreach($result as $row) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Family'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
}
```

As for the **HTML File**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-  scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
 <title>Test</title>

 <link href="assests/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


 <script type="text/javascript"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="assests/js/plugins/forms/ui.spinner.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assests/js/plugins/forms/jquery.mousewheel.js">  </script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assests/js/plugins/tables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assests/js/plugins/tables/jquery.sortable.js">  </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assests/js/plugins/tables/jquery.resizable.js"></script>
 <script>
 function showName(str)
 {
   if (str=="")
      {
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
 return;
      } 
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
  else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","getName.php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }</script>

 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="txtHint">

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: where is <tbody> closed?

Comment: Show your css code related to a table. Try to see if it works when you simply place static table where it is shown when loaded with ajax. And take a look at Developer Tools or Firebug(in firefox). They will show you applied styles and help to debug an issue. Possibly your css file is not correctly linked (wrong path) or structure is different from one you expect

Comment: Thanks for the tips.
I tried the same with a different table class ( Static) and everything is perfect.. I was hoping to use the dynamic one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed a div in PHP file.

Use the following code:

```
echo "</tbody></table></div>";
```

Instead of

```
echo "</table>";
```

In that div is responsible for the CSS format

Comment: Thanks, indeed the tag was missing

Comment: I want but I cant as my reputation hasn't reached 15pts yet. Cheers

Comment: I will mark as Correct but need to add that the table class was an issue as well if anyone is referring to this example.

Comment: @RajaKhoury what is the issue with table class? can you describe it.

Comment: I have not figure that out yet. When I switched to a "static" table class it solved the prob, of course the tag as well. I need to debug further.

Comment: may this is due to there is define the css for the class that you are using check your css file to get the differences.

Answer (score 0):

looks to be css class issue 
remove echo " from php file and try using

```
document.getElementById("txtHint").html =xmlhttp.responseText;
```